# How to tunnel pgAdmin over wsl2 to CF Database Service?

Tags: linux, postgresql, cloud-foundry, wsl-2

how can I tunnel my local Windows pgAdmin Client over wsl2 to my cf database?
Im already connected with my server: cf ssh -L 8888:servername:5432 app-name
Im trying to connect per localhost 127.0.0.1 and Port 8888.
I dont want to install cf cli extra for windows just running over wsl2.
Hope for some help, much colleges have the same problem.

Comment: Not a WSL2 expert, but from what I've seen (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions) it runs in a VM, so localhost for WSL2 isn't localhost on your machine, it's localhost on the VM. Run `cf ssh` in WSL2 to set up the tunnel there or you'd need another SSH tunnel from your machine to WSL2. Again, not a WSL2 expert, maybe someone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

```
cf login [-a API_URL] [-u USERNAME] [-s SPACE]
cf env [APP_NAME]
cf ssh APP_NAME -L 9105:IP:PORT
```

Bind local wsl2 port for example 9105

pgAdmin Connection:
Host: 127.0.0.1 (localhost doenst work! You can connect but not push sql query)
If you have entered localhost you will get the error message SSL negation packet socket is not connected.
Port 9105

Now you guys are fine if you'll have this problem. Have fun :)